# Speed up a query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, searchkick

I'm working on a Rails app that can have 20-30k records for a single query that will render on a page.  I'd appreciate some feedback on this query thanks!

The Controller

```
def index
  if params[:advertiser].blank?
    @products = Product.all
  else
    @advertiser_name = Advertiser.find_by(name: params[:advertiser]).name
    @products = Product.where(advertiser: @advertiser_name)
  end
end
```

The Product object has all the records and can be looked up by advertiser name.

The View

```
<div class="product-listing">
  <ul>
  <% @products.each do |p| %>
    <li id="name">Product Name: <%= p.product_name %></li>
    <li id="advertiser">Advertiser: <%= p.advertiser %></li>
    <li id="designer">Designer: <%= p.designer %></li>
    <li id="price">Price: <%= p.price %></li>
    <li id="commission">Commission: <%= p.commission %></li>
    <li id="url">Url: <%= p.product_url %></li>
    <hr>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Current Load time

```
Completed 200 OK in 35531ms (Views: 31808.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3689.6ms)
```

It would probably help to show you guys my Schema.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151227085753) do

create_table "advertisers", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "product_id"
  t.string   "product_name"
  t.string   "product_url"
  t.string   "advertiser"
  t.string   "designer"
  t.string   "price"
  t.string   "commission"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
 end

 add_index "products", ["advertiser"], name: "index_products_on_advertiser"
```

end

Comment: I obviously want to speed this up considerably.

Answer (score 0):

```
@products_with_details = Product.joins('inner join advertisers on product.advertiser_id = advertisers.id')
  .joins('inner join designers on product.designer_id = designers.id')
  .select('
    product.name as product_name,
    designers.name as designer_name,
    advertisers.name as advertiser_name
  ').all
```

will prepare product objects with product_name, designer_name, advertiser_name as attributes, which you can use on view like

Advertiser: <%= p.advertiser_name %>

this wont issue queries per each product record for displaying information which lies on other tables like advertisers, designers etc.

Comment: Or simply `Product.includes(:designer, :adverister)` which would also preload all associations and not make a separate request for each one.

Comment: I don't have a designers table I have edited my question to reflect that with my schema as it stands